# How to extract a substring from a string using a string match condition in SHELL

Tags: bash, shell

I have to extract a substring from this.

```
- Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2183, sessionid = 
   0x1000c22ff510020, negotiated timeout = 120000 WATCHER:: WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected 
   type:None path:null [zk: localhost:2183(CONNECTED) 0] addauth digest super:testing [zk: 
   localhost:2183(CONNECTED) 1] ls /live_nodes [rn3-gcs02.rno.foo.com:8985_solr, rn3- 
   gcsb.rno.foo.com:8985_solr] [zk: localhost:2183(CONNECTED) 2]
```

The substring to be extracted is

> [rn3-gcs02.rno.foo.com:8985_solr, rn3- 
>          gcsb.rno.foo.com:8985_solr]

it's a dynamic substring which can have 2 or more elements

Comment: Determined how? Just always whatever comes after `ls /live-nodes`?

Comment: Also, are the linebreaks real/important, or can the whole thing just be coalesced into one line before doing any matching?

Comment: BTW, note that in general, you're expected to show what you tried and what specific problem you had while making that attempt in asking a question.

Comment: alwys comes after ls /live-nodes. line breaks are not real. its single string line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re='ls /live_nodes (\[[^]]+\])'
[[ $s =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

...emits, with your input in `$s`:

```
[rn3-gcs02.rno.foo.com:8985_solr, rn3-
   gcsb.rno.foo.com:8985_solr]
```